# How to populate one list using another list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I essentially have two lists. List A which is more of a detailed list and List B is more high level. How do I go about using List B (detail) to automtically populate List A (summary)?

Comment: You probably want two different views of List B rather than two separate lists. What is the data and how are you summarizing it?

Comment: The data is different schedules within different Lines of business. I am summarizing it by Key business element count (being that that each schedule has a # of KBE's)

Comment: That sounds like something that you could resolve with [grouping](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Sort-and-group-data-in-a-Data-View-923202b5-d512-44a0-88ce-ba799a429a6c?ui=en-US&rs=en-CA&ad=CA) and [totals](http://www.mssharepointtips.com/tip.asp?id=1012). If you update your question with the specific fields and their data types (eg. Line of Business - Choice column) and the specific requirements for the summarization, I'd be happy to walk you through creating the detail and summary views.

Comment: Another option might be to keep them separate lists and have the summary one updated via workflow from the detail one, but you'll need to provide the specifics of your lists in order for anyone to guide you through that, too.

Answer (score 1):

To automate the data population from List B to List A, there are 2 general methods, which are applicable to either Developers or Administrators

**For SharePoint Developers**

- You can create an Event Receiver and attach it to the List B to observe for List Item Added event
- For each new added item, you can check if it's found in List A or not, if not, then just add to List A

**For SharePoint Administrators**

- A preferred method is to use Powershell to loop through List B, and add those distinct items to List A
- To automate, you can create a Windows Scheduler task to run based on a predefined schedule

Comment: Event receivers work, but are far from my favorite way of doing stuff, wait until you see the fun and games that ensue when List B has an event receiver that inserts stuff into List A, creating a "Sorcerer's Apprentice" style recursion....

Answer (score 0):

There is no out-of-the-box way to have one list automatically update/edit another list without some sort of customization -- workflow, timer job, event receiver, etc..